# HTML scraping vs json file in aspnet framework?

Tags: python, asp.net, database, razor, web-scraping

I would like to download the data in this table:
http://portal.ujn.gov.rs/Izvestaji/IzvestajiVelike.aspx

I know how to use selenium to go through the pages and the CSS selectors are helpful enough that it shouldn't be too difficult to get all the data...

However, I am curious if anyone knows some way of getting to a json or whatever intermediary object is used to make the html? As in, whatever the raw data format file that gets exported by the server is? Is this possible with aspnet frameworks?

I have found such solutions in the past, but with much simpler web pages and web pages with get requests...

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Taking a look at the website (I have no experience with Russian at all but not like it maters much.) It looks to me like it is pulling the information from a database via PHP (In my book the "old" way of doing it) not a JSON file. Which means that your basically stuck doing it the normal web scraping route like you said OR to find a SQL injection (which I am in NO WAY SUGGESTING as it is illegal?) to be able to bypass the limitations of there crappy search page.

Comment: I thought it was using Ajax callbacks and not php? I'm pretty sure it is some standard ASP.NET framework, but I don't know anything about those. Also, the data is public by law, just made hard to download... thanks!